# How to use masonry create dynamic height cell,the layout is mix when scroll the tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, tableview, masonry

In the ViewController,I catch the cell height and set dynamitc height for row at each indexPath

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     PFBubbleData *dataModel = (PFBubbleData *)self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
     PFBubbleLayout *layout = dataModel.layout;
     return layout.bubbleHeight;
}
```

and get the cell from cell queue the update it with dataModel witch contains the layout model

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     PFBubbleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PFBubbleCell"];
     [cell updateViewWithData:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
     return cell;
}
```

when create cell,add subview to the contentView,(each subviews has already created in the getMethod,so here add the subviews directly)

```
-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    LOG_METHOD
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.224 green:0.671 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.faceImageView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.containerView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Finally,I update the subviews when I setup the dataModel to the cell,and use masonry layout subviews

```
-(void)updateViewWithData:(id)dataEntity {
    LOG_METHOD
    self.dataModel = (PFBubbleData*)dataEntity;
    //update the subeViewFrame is Needed after the data changed
    [self.faceImageView setImage:self.dataModel.avatarImage];
    [self setupFrameAndConstraints];
}
```

the masonry layout is below

```
-(void)setupFrameAndConstraints {
[self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0));
}];

if (self.dataModel.bubbleDirection == PFBubbleDirection_Other) {
    //                self.avaterImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.dataModel.layout.board_margin,
    //                                                        self.dataModel.layout.board_margin, 50, 50);
    //                self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.avaterImageView.frame) + self.dataModel.layout.board_margin,
    //                                                      CGRectGetMinY(self.avaterImageView.frame),
    //                                                      self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.width,
    //                                                      self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.height);

        [self.faceImageView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).offset(contentMargin);
            make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_left).offset(contentMargin);
            make.width.mas_equalTo(@(50));
            make.height.mas_equalTo(@(50));
        }];

        [self.containerView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.faceImageView.mas_top);
            make.left.equalTo(self.faceImageView.mas_right).offset(contentMargin);
            make.width.mas_equalTo(self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.width);
            make.bottom.mas_equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(-contentMargin);
        }];
    }else if(self.dataModel.bubbleDirection == PFBubbleDirection_Self){
    //                self.avaterImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - self.dataModel.layout.board_margin - 50,
    //                                                        self.dataModel.layout.board_margin, 50, 50);
    //
    //                self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.avaterImageView.frame) - self.dataModel.layout.board_margin - self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.width,
    //                                                      CGRectGetMinY(self.avaterImageView.frame),
    //                                                      self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.width,
    //                                                      self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.height);

        [self.faceImageView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).offset(contentMargin);
            make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_right).offset(-contentMargin);
            make.width.mas_equalTo(@(50));
            make.height.mas_equalTo(@(50));
        }];

        [self.containerView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.faceImageView.mas_top);
            make.right.equalTo(self.faceImageView.mas_left).offset(-contentMargin);
            make.width.mas_equalTo(self.dataModel.layout.contentSize.width);
            make.bottom.mas_equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(-contentMargin);
        }];
    }
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

it appear like this:
[image]
 [image]

when I scroll the table view  the log like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I never used masonry but don´t forget that the tableview reuses cells and you call  `-(void)updateViewWithData:(id)dataEntity` on a reused cell. So you call it a second (or a third, forth) time.

So you set your constraints a second time.

Set a flag (for example you can name id `layoutDone` that you set on true when you called the  `-(void)updateViewWithData:(id)dataEntity` for the first time and don´t call this function again when the cell is reused.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem lie the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You could try declaring the datasource method as

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     PFBubbleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PFBubbleCell"];
     if(cell) {
       cell = [[PFBubbleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PFBubbleCell"];
     }
     [cell updateViewWithData:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
     return cell;
}
```